# How can I access spring config server properties through a web browser?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud-config-server

I managed to access the properties file of my config server exactly one time. Something changed in my configuration it seemed and I am not able to repeat that....

I'm desperate at this point. I'm trying to figure this out since 2 days and my mental health is starting to suffer.

My **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demos</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demos</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

And finally the only class in the project

```
package com.example.demos;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class DemosApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemosApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Since I am not using a git but o local file my application.properties file inside my resource folder looks like this:

```
server.port=8888
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=/home/leobuilt/IdeaProjects/demos/src/main/resources/config
management.security.enabled=false
```

pointing to the local folder where my configuration is residing

This is the configuration file called ever.properties:

```
server=Hello world
```

The whole project structure:

[image]

Please... what is the correct URL to access the properties of this file via a browser?

[image]

I have found several tutorials where people access properties file this way.
Even I managed to do this once as can be seen here.(The file was named *newsservice-config.properties* in this project, but configuration was identical)

[image]

Can anyone please explain some logic behind all of this while not using any git?

Comment: You have to make an custom access to your file. Default conf NEVER show the config files to an untrusted client like an browser. You maybe find a solution if you look the `Actuator` part of `Spring`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write code to list your properties and then display the data this metod returns on a webpage. We do this with the following method:

```
private Map<String, Map<String, String>> getEnvironmentPropertyGroups() {
    MutablePropertySources propertySources = ((AbstractEnvironment) env).getPropertySources();

    Map<String, Map<String, String>> propertyGroups = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    propertySources.forEach(propertySource -> {
        if (propertySource instanceof EnumerablePropertySource) {
            Map<String, String> properties = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            EnumerablePropertySource enumerablePropertySource = (EnumerablePropertySource) propertySource;
            for (String key : enumerablePropertySource.getPropertyNames()) {
                Object value = enumerablePropertySource.getProperty(key);
                properties.put(key, getValueForKey(key, value));
            }

            propertyGroups.put(propertySource.getName(), properties);
        }
    });
    return propertyGroups;
}
```

Comment: This might work, but keep in mind, showing the conf properties to an untrusted client may lead to big security issue. The main idea is : `a server never tell it's own conf through it's public facade.`

Comment: @Zorglube Good point! Should only be used for testing or on secured webpages.

Comment: even on secured endpoint it's a bad practice ;-)